# Mongodb not connecting to persistent volume

Tags: mongodb, terraform, linode

I'm using this terraform config to deploy mongodb to my kubernetes cluster

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "mongodb_replicaset_mongodb" {
  metadata {
    name      = "mongodb-replicaset-mongodb"
    namespace = "default"

    labels = {
      app     = "mongodb-replicaset"
    }
  }

  data = {
    "mongod.conf" = "{}\n"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "mongodb_replicaset" {
  metadata {
    name      = "mongodb-replicaset"
    namespace = "default"

    labels = {
      app     = "mongodb-replicaset"
    }

    annotations = {
      "service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints" = "true"
    }
  }

  spec {
    port {
      name = "mongodb"
      port = 27017
    }

    selector = {
      app     = "mongodb-replicaset"
    }

    cluster_ip                  = "None"
    type                        = "ClusterIP"
    publish_not_ready_addresses = true
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_stateful_set" "mongodb_replicaset" {
  metadata {
    name      = "mongodb-replicaset"
    namespace = "default"

    labels = {
      app     = "mongodb-replicaset"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app     = "mongodb-replicaset"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "mongodb-replicaset"
        }
      }

      spec {
        volume {
          name = "config"

          config_map {
            name = "mongodb-replicaset-mongodb"
          }
        }

        volume {
          name = "workdir"
        }

        volume {
          name = "configdir"
        }

        container {
          name    = "mongodb-replicaset"
          image   = "mongo:4.4"
          command = ["mongod"]
          args    = ["--config=/data/configdb/mongod.conf", "--dbpath=/data/db", "--replSet=rs0", "--port=27017", "--bind_ip=0.0.0.0"]

          port {
            name           = "mongodb"
            container_port = 27017
          }

          volume_mount {
            name       = "datadir"
            mount_path = "/data/db"
          }

          volume_mount {
            name       = "configdir"
            mount_path = "/data/configdb"
          }

          volume_mount {
            name       = "workdir"
            mount_path = "/work-dir"
          }

          resources {
            limits     = {
              cpu    = "100m"
              memory = "100Mi"
            }

            requests = {
              cpu    = "100m"
              memory = "100Mi"
            }
          }

          liveness_probe {
            exec {
              command = ["mongo", "--eval", "db.adminCommand('ping')"]
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 30
            timeout_seconds       = 5
            period_seconds        = 10
            success_threshold     = 1
            failure_threshold     = 3
          }

          readiness_probe {
            exec {
              command = ["mongo", "--eval", "db.adminCommand('ping')"]
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 5
            timeout_seconds       = 1
            period_seconds        = 10
            success_threshold     = 1
            failure_threshold     = 3
          }

          image_pull_policy = "IfNotPresent"
        }

        termination_grace_period_seconds = 30

        security_context {
          run_as_user     = 999
          run_as_non_root = true
          fs_group        = 999
        }
      }
    }

    volume_claim_template {
      metadata {
        name = "datadir"
      }

      spec {
        access_modes       = ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storage_class_name = "linode-block-storage-retain"

        resources {
          requests = {
            storage = "50Gi"
          }
        }
      }
    }

    service_name = "mongodb-replicaset"
  }
}
```

I know I need to have a persistent volume if I'm deploying a database and this is the way I've figured out how to deploy this database. The problem is that I get this message from kubernetes

```
no nodes available to schedule pods
MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-9adf2a456cbf4d66" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Unable to find device path out of attempted paths: [/dev/disk/by-id/linode-pvc9adf2a456cbf4d66 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Linode_Volume_pvc9adf2a456cbf4d66]
Back-off restarting failed container
```

I see in my Linode dashboard that a block storage volume is created and attached to the container but kubernetes is having an issue. How do I resolve this so that my mongodb is deployed with it's volume.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, May be, you have defined the volume name as datadir. Therefore, Kubernetes will create a mount path for this volume in the container at /datadir. However, in your container spec, you are trying to mount the volume at /data/db.

Changing the mountPath to /datadir will ensure that the volume is mounted at the correct location in the container and should resolve the error you are seeing

Also, I think, k8s is unable to mount the pesistent volume to your mongodb statefulset.
The err msg indicates, the kubernetes can not locate the device path for block storage volume.

Check if storageClassName in config of volume_claim_template matches the storageClassName of the block storage volume you have created.

Also, check the nodename in pod.spec.affinity section of your manifest is set correctly. K8s may try to schedule the pod on a node that doesn't have the necessary block storage volume.

Last but not least check the pod's logs , do you get any hints there?

Once you make the changes. I recommend, try deleting the StatefulSet and redeploy it.